# How to do a nested COALESCE subquery in a join for 3 different tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 3 tables, And using query, have table sorted on distinct on group/product.

Now I would like to add a child table each of these 3 table with say just 1 column `default_something`

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pg.id, p.prod_id)
    pg.group_name, p.name AS prod_name, v.version
FROM product_group pg
LEFT JOIN product p ON pg.id = p.group_id
LEFT JOIN version v ON v.prod_id = p.prod_id
ORDER BY pg.id, p.prod_id, v.version DESC;
```

Product Group Table

```
id  group_name
---------------------------
1   Nice
2   Very Nice
```

Product table

```
prod_id  name      group_id
---------------------------
1       something     2
2       psp3          1
3.      other one     2
```

Version Table

```
version_id  prod_id    version
---------------------------
1           2           1.0
2           2           1.1
3           3           2.3
4           1           0.1
5.          1           0.2
```

Product Group Child Table

```
pgt_child_id  group_id    default_something
---------------------------------
1             2            root2
2             1            root1
```

Product Child table

```
pt_child_id  prod_id      default_something
-------------------------------------------
1             3            override2
```

Version Child Table

```
v_child_id  version_id    default_something
-------------------------------------------
1             2           winner
```

Running the query  [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3e5cfbf63f0be6ffacc93688f431d106)  I get this now...

```
Group_name  prod_name    version
---------------------------------
Nice        psp3          1.1
Very Nice   something     0.2
Very Nice   other one     2.3
```

What I want is like this

```
Group_name  prod_name    version    default_something
-----------------------------------------------------
Nice        psp3          1.1       winner
Very Nice   something     0.2.      root2
Very Nice   other one     2.3.      override2
```

Basically if `Version table` has the field `default_something`.. that always wins.. If `Version Table` does not and if `Product Table` has the field `default_something`, that would win.. And `Group Product Table` basically has the lowest priority so if `Version Table` and `Product Table` does not have the field then value from `Group Product Table` wins.

I would assume `SELECT COALESCE()` would work to get the value which wins from 3 child tables.. I just have not figured out how to put that in a subquery with a join or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make just a `COALESCE` with with three subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pg.id, p.prod_id)
    pg.group_name, p.name AS prod_name, v.version,
COALESCE((select default_something from version_child where version_id = v.id),
(select default_something from product_child where prod_id = p.prod_id),
(select default_something from product_group_child where group_id = pg.id)
) as something
FROM product_group pg
LEFT JOIN product p ON pg.id = p.group_id
LEFT JOIN version v ON v.prod_id = p.prod_id
ORDER BY pg.id, p.prod_id, v.version DESC;
```

see the amended [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e7e83db0ae57e1dcee221e4cfd4347a5)

or left join the three tables and make the coalesce on the default_somethings

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pg.id, p.prod_id)
    pg.group_name, p.name AS prod_name, v.version,
COALESCE(v2.default_something,
p2.default_something,
pg2.default_something
) as something
FROM product_group pg
LEFT JOIN product p ON pg.id = p.group_id
LEFT JOIN version v ON v.prod_id = p.prod_id
LEFT JOIN version_child v2 ON v2.version_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN product_child p2 ON p2.prod_id = p.prod_id
LEFT JOIN product_group_child pg2 ON pg2.group_id = pg.id
ORDER BY pg.id, p.prod_id, v.version DESC;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a5dc676a0df8dab6d04f771b2a49320b)